# R manipulating data frame pivot

Tags: r, reshape

I have some data in a csv file as below.

```
Food            Calories    Cholesterol Total_Fat   Sodium 
Frozen_Broccoli 73.8            0           0.8         68.2 
Carrots,Raw 74.8            23.7            0           0.1
```

code to create that data is (updated the code after a comment from user [Drew Steen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/741348/drew-steen) below):

```
Food=c('Frozen Broccoli',   'Carrots,Raw')
Cholesterol=c('0',  '23.7')
Total_Fat=c('0.8',  '0')
Sodium=c('68.2',    '0.1')
Calories=c('73.8',  '74.8')
Food=c('Frozen Broccoli',   'Carrots,Raw')
original=data.frame(Food, Cholesterol,Total_Fat,Sodium,Calories)
View(original)
```

I would like to transpose part of data so that it looks like below.

```
Frozen_Broccoli    Calories X73.8
Frozen_Broccoli Cholesterol   0.0
Frozen_Broccoli   Total_Fat   0.8
Frozen_Broccoli      Sodium  68.2
Carrots,Raw    Calories  74.8
Carrots,Raw Cholesterol  23.7
Carrots,Raw   Total_Fat   0.0
Carrots,Raw      Sodium   0.1
```

I can create the data using Excel and vba. But is their a way to do the same in R?

Comment: check out the `reshape2` package

Comment: is there any specific command? any refrence example?...also how did you change my original question to add colors to columns and rows? your change makes my question very easier to understand...and i would like to learn how to ask questions effectively

Comment: http://stat405.had.co.nz/lectures/19-tables.pdf

Comment: Also http://bit.ly/13keFbS

Comment: On "[how to ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [questions effectively](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Comment: On [code formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in your questions (and answers!). Hope this will make your SO life a little bit easier!

Comment: thanks for comments and will follow them in future. when i copy my code from R studio and paste it to ask a question...all '>" remain with the code...is there a shortcut to get rid of them? as of now i paste my code in notepad and replace ">" with"". i already searched google a lot - i typed "remove > stackexchange", "remove > R code" but didnt get a good answer and also looked at links given above...would appreciate an answer

Comment: That's a pretty terrible way to create your data! Everything is stored as `factor`s while I'm assuming that you meant for the numbers to be numeric....

Comment: @AnandaMahto what is a better way...would like to listen to your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you supply does not, I think, precisely reproduce your `.csv` file. (Try `names(original)` to see how). Try this

```
original <- read.csv("your_data.csv")
require(reshape2)
new_df <- melt(original, id.vars="Food")
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to serve two purposes:

1. Address a question in the comments in how to share reproducible data in a better way.
2. Represent base R with `stack`.

#### Part 1: Data creation.

*Note that the numbers are not quoted and that we can put them in a `data.frame` directly. This means that there are fewer objects littering the workspaces of the people trying to answer your question*.

```
original <- data.frame(
  Food = c('Frozen Broccoli', 'Carrots,Raw'),
  Cholesterol = c(0, 23.7), 
  Total_Fat = c(0.8, 0),
  Sodium = c(68.2, 0.1),
  Calories = c(73.8, 74.8))
original
#              Food Cholesterol Total_Fat Sodium Calories
# 1 Frozen Broccoli         0.0       0.8   68.2     73.8
# 2     Carrots,Raw        23.7       0.0    0.1     74.8
```

#### An alternative solution

*The "reshaping" process can be done with `stack` from base R. Drop the first column when you are stacking the data. Use `cbind` to put it back in.*

Generally, `stack` is faster than `melt`. There is also `unlist` but that is very cumbersome for this particular problem.

```
cbind(original[1], stack(original[-1]))
#              Food values         ind
# 1 Frozen Broccoli    0.0 Cholesterol
# 2     Carrots,Raw   23.7 Cholesterol
# 3 Frozen Broccoli    0.8   Total_Fat
# 4     Carrots,Raw    0.0   Total_Fat
# 5 Frozen Broccoli   68.2      Sodium
# 6     Carrots,Raw    0.1      Sodium
# 7 Frozen Broccoli   73.8    Calories
# 8     Carrots,Raw   74.8    Calories
```